# Struggling with RegEx validation and formating for specfici ID format

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have couple specific string formatting i want to achieve for different entities:

Entity 1: `1111-abcd-1111` or `1111-abcd-111111`

Entity 2: `[10 any symbol or letter(all cap) or number]-[3 letters]`

Entity 3: `[3 letters all cap]-[3 any]-[5 number]`

Not sure if Regex is best approach, because i also want to use this as validator when user starts typing the char's it will check against that Entity selected and then against it's RegEx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex with some input strings:

```js
const strings = [
  '1111-abcd-1111',     // match
  '1111-abcd-111111',   // match
  '1111-abcd-1111111',  // no match
  'ABCS@!%!3!-ABC',     // match
  'ABCS@!%!3!-ABCD',    // nomatch
  'ABC-@A3-12345',      // match
  'ABC-@A3-1234'        // no match
];
const re = /^([0-9]{4}-[a-z]{4}-[0-9]{4,6}|.{10}-[A-Za-z]{3}|[A-Z]{3}-.{3}-[0-9]{5})$/;
strings.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + re.test(str));
});
```

Result:

```
1111-abcd-1111 => true
1111-abcd-111111 => true
1111-abcd-1111111 => false
ABCS@!%!3!-ABC => true
ABCS@!%!3!-ABCD => false
ABC-@A3-12345 => true
ABC-@A3-1234 => false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` - anchor text at beginning, e.g. what follows must be at the beginning of the string
- `(` - group start
- `[0-9]{4}-[a-z]{4}-[0-9]{4,6}` - 4 digits, `-`, 4 lowercase letters, `-`, 4-6 digits
- `|` - logical OR
- `.{10}-[A-Za-z]{3}` - any 10 chars, `-`, 3 letters
- `|` - logical OR
- `[A-Z]{3}-.{3}-[0-9]{5}` - 3 uppercase letters, `-`, any 3 chars, `-`, 5 digits
- `)` - group end
- `$` - anchor at end of string

Your definition is not clear; you can tweak the regex as needed.